Subdividing grid in QGIS
I tried following the same procedure as detailed in this answer to Subdividing square buffer in sub-units using QGIS?, in order to subdivide a grid I have however I run into a problem on the edges of my area of interest. If the larger grid square is not complete, I clipped the overall grid to my area of interest, then the sub grid will end up all messed up, see below.


To avoid the issue of edges outside of the area of interest, you can use the processing toolbox>geometry by expression that will create actual geometries, instead of the Geometry by expression in your layer styling
In any case, the solution you refer to takes one of the "square's" segment as a reference length. If the square is not perfect, or if due to the projection, each side of the "square" actually has a different length, the splitting lines will not be properly placed.
Use this modified expression so that it works on any 4 sided polygon:
collect_geometries (
    with_variable(
        'no',
        5, 
            array_foreach (
                generate_series (1, @no-1),
                collect_geometries(
                    make_line (
                        line_interpolate_point( 
                            make_line (
                                point_n($geometry, 1),
                                point_n($geometry, 2)
                            ),
                            length(make_line (
                                point_n($geometry, 1),
                                point_n($geometry, 2)
                            ))/@no*@element
                        ),
                        line_interpolate_point( 
                            make_line (
                                point_n($geometry, 4),
                                point_n($geometry, 3)
                            ),
                            length(make_line (
                                point_n($geometry, 4),
                                point_n($geometry, 3)
                            ))/@no*@element
                        )
                    ),
                    make_line (
                        line_interpolate_point( 
                            make_line (
                                point_n($geometry, 2),
                                point_n($geometry, 3)
                            ),
                            length(make_line (
                                point_n($geometry, 2),
                                point_n($geometry, 3)
                            ))/@no*@element
                        ),
                        line_interpolate_point( 
                            make_line (
                                point_n($geometry, 1),
                                point_n($geometry, 4)
                            ),
                            length(make_line (
                                point_n($geometry, 1),
                                point_n($geometry, 4)
                            ))/@no*@element
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
    )
)

This is what you get when applying it in the Geometry generator:


That definitely looks a lot better than what I was getting before, thank you. Now I just gotta figure out why it's turning my dashed lines into solid lines when exporting to PDF for printing lol
